# How to lazy render a very long list of data?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've created a SPA Hearthstone card search that shows all (currently ~1200) cards on the same page. [Site](http://www.wizard-poker.com/). The problem I have is that due to all 1200 cards being displayed on the same page it takes really long time to render. How would I best tackle this problem?

My ideas so far:

- Lazy render parts of array that aren't immediately visible. This would seem best, but I don't know if it's possible and how. There's [a package](https://github.com/onefinestay/react-lazy-render) for react that seems to do this, so I guess it's possible somehow? I guess I could make a separate array for shown cards, which I would lazy append from first array based on how much the user has scrolled
- Pagination. Obvious one, but it makes for some counter-intuitive behaviour along with the filters I have. I would like to avoid using pagination if possible.

For reference - [here's the code](https://github.com/d1am0nd/wp/blob/master/vue/src/components/partials/Cards.vue) for rendering the cards.

How would I go about making this render faster? Is lazy rendering possible and how is it best done?

Comment: Have you looked into using an existing component like https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/#!/

Comment: I have not. This actually seems quite promising. I'll try it out.

Comment: @BertEvans perfect!